# Python: Print only one time inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, opencv3.0

I have a code where I want capture a video from a camera. I want to use Logging library of Python to get messages on the shell or export them to a text file.

Here is a part of my code where inside the while loop I want to print *Camera Opened Successfully*

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import logging as log

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mpg')

while True:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit = 15.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    gray1 = clahe.apply(gray)
```

but what I get in the shell is this:

[image]

until I terminated the running script. Any idea on how to make it print only once.

Comment: Um, use an `if` statement.

Comment: Side-note: Never use `if ret == True:`. Just use `if ret:`; it's more Pythonic (as well as more concise and ever so slightly faster). If you really need to test for `True` specifically, and not some other truthy value, you'd want `if ret is True:`, which, unlike `if ret == True:`, won't treat `ret` values of `1`, `1.0`, etc. as equal to `True`. But you rarely even want that, just check `if ret:`. Same goes for `ret == False`; you almost always want `not ret`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import logging as log

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mpg')
hasOpened = False

while True:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if ret and not hasOpened:
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')
        hasOpened = True
```

If you want to break out of the loop after printing, follow Matt's answer. This option will continue in the loop and only print once.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra boolean to track whether you have printed it out before:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import logging as log

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mpg')
printed = False

while True:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if ret == True and not printed:
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')
        printed = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You must break out of the loop

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import logging as log

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mpg')

while True:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')
        break
```

Comment: It will just exit the while loop and continue after that. Do you have other statements in the while loop you want to execute?

Comment: Yes, a lot of statements. But its okay an answer is posted and it works well for me thanks for your care :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the while loop, also since you would like to break out of the loop as soon as you get `ret` True you can use:

```
ret = False
while not ret:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if ret:
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')
    # any other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to trigger the log and then make it false. ret is to be made False when you are ready to exit the loop so that it will exit

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import logging as log

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mpg')
ret = True
logit = True
while ret:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if logit == True:
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')
        logit = False

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit = 15.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    gray1 = clahe.apply(gray)
    // process remainder of situation setting
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to take advantage of default mutable parameters in Python:

```py
def print_once(string, bucket=[]):
    """
    Print only one time

    >>> print_once("foo")
    foo
    >>> print_once("foo")
    """
    if string not in bucket:
        print(string)
        bucket.append(string)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to use your main loop to handle your application logic, and it doesn't make sense to have one loop for detecting if it is opened and another for working with it then I think what you want is to set a variable to determine if the state has changed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import logging as log

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mpg')
old_ret = False

while True:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    if old_ret == False and ret == True:
        old_red = True
        log.warning('Camera Opened Successfully')

    if ret == True:
        # Do other things that need the camera but no log
```

Comment: You forgot to set old_ret to True